# retrieve time from firebase database and display it in textView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The retrieve time should be display below the Time textview
[image: app UI]

[image: database structure]

I want to fetch the stored time and display it user.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user_time_table");

myRef.child("Y71VckCvTPVyqLCtrSQNHRiThsc2").child("Mondey").child("time").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String time = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                        myEditText.setText(time);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

This is hardcoded solution. If you want to make it more flexible, you can change "Y71VckCvTPVyqLCtrSQNHRiThsc2" to current user's id, for example:

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String id = user.getUid();
```

and then use this id instead of hardcoded String.

Comment: it not working,,,Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Answer (score 0):

```
 String x = String.valueOf(drposts.getTime());
        long milliSeconds= Long.parseLong(x);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String dateAsString = sdf.format (milliSeconds);
        myEditText.setText(dateAsString );
//first convert the time value in string and store into it long after that
```

//define the simple date format and store it again in string and pass it text view
//drposts is my object class u an use 
//String x = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);